# Why we put only single square brackets while dropping column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Whenever we are dropping two column in a dataframe, we enclose the column names with a single square bracket. Below is the code:

```py
df.drop(columns=['first','last'],inplace = True)
```

Why are we not putting two square brackets like below:

```py
df.drop(columns=[['first','last']],inplace = True)
```

Because whenever we try to access multiple columns, we use two square brackets, like the below code.

```py
df[['first','last']]
```

I'm not sure. There might be something wrong in my understanding. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `df[['first','last']]`, the outer bracket has been used for indexing and inner bracket has been used for providing the list of columns you want to access.

In `df.drop(columns=['first','last'],inplace = True)` , the only bracket has been used which is for providing the list of columns. You dont need any other bracket here because `drop()` will get list of columns needs to be dropped. There is no need of indexing.